# How to replace word in large string excluding tags like img/a

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to link topics present in my description by its relevant topic...Now here I am using preg_replace() to do the same, but now I need help in formatting regex pattern to do that....

As challenges faced by me are:

1) Description can contain all types of html tags

2) My replace function should not replaces anything coming between  tag and   tag

3) it should not replace any attribute of any tag present withing description...like if there is string Style and Beauty and if i want to link Style as my topic..so in this case it should not link 'style' attribute of  tag instead it should link Style from "Style and Beauty" string

Any kind of help on above query will be appreciated....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Here we go again... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: From the link @tdammers provided: __HTML and regex go together like love, marriage, and ritual infanticide__, just don't. Really: don't. For your own sanity and those around you: don't

Answer (score 1):

Use either the `DOMParser` class or one of the several XML parsing libraries available in PHP, depending on how well formed your input is.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment: Regular Expressions are not suitable for stateful or recursive parsing, that is, they can match in quite advanced ways, but anything that requires recursion or state, most notably, anything that is somehow tree-like, can't be parsed using regular expressions. Some regex dialects (e.g. Perl regular expressions) feature back-references and other constructs that extend regular expressions beyond strictly regular parsing, but even with those, things are going to be painful at best.

Instead, do the sane thing: find a DOM parser that works on your input (e.g. PHP's own DOMDocument API), and do your processing on the resulting DOM tree. An approach that should work well is to walk through your DOM tree, recursively, and then at each node, see if it's a text node; if it is, apply your simple search-and-replace logic to its contents, otherwise descend into it and / or leave it unchanged. Alternatively, you can throw an XPath expression at it to give you the text nodes, and then change them directly. Or you can hook a suitable replacer function into an XslProcessor and do the replacing in XSLT - this is fairly straightforward if you're familiar with XSLT, but if you're not, the DOM walker is probably easier to implement.